# Android Auto app runs fine in desktop-head-unit emulator but not showing up in Volkswagen launcher

Tags: android, android-auto, app-launcher

To start with Android Auto development I checked out some example projects (https://github.com/android/car-samples/tree/main/car_app_library), compiled them in Android studio (fixed some depreciation issues) and successfully tested them in desktop-head-unit emulator. Also set up a small Hello World on my own, which works the same way. I made sure that in Android Auto settings on the phone "unknown sources" is checked. All good unless I connect to my real car system. All the apps are not showing up in the car launcher, also not able to add them through "settings" app. Restarted the phone, compiled apps to lowest possible SDK target version. Nothing worked out.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how did you enabled "unknown sources" on Android Auto device? there is no option in there... can you provide a device/manufacturer of your Android Audio unit?

afaik there is no other way for testing app than mentioned simulator, no option for running debug in a physical car. app MUST be distributed through Google Play

> To test your app in real vehicles, it must be installed from a trusted source such as the Play Store. During the early phases of development, you can use Internal App Sharing or an Internal Test Track to distribute your app to devices without going through the Play Store review process.

[source](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#real-vehicles)

Comment: Open the Android Auto app on your phone, hit the three dots in the top right corner and choose "developer settings" (mine is German, so I just guess the English naming). Scroll down and check "unknown sources". I thought that would it not need necessary to go through play store. Can I release something to play store which only can be accessed by me?

Comment: good to know, I've got only short chance for experimenting with a "real" car, also without luck like you. but then done research and found linked doc... and yes, you can release app through [Internal App Sharing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/), which needs to configure a mail list of users, which can access app, just set only yours :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#real-vehicles) - The "unknown sources" setting only applies to media and messaging apps and doesn't apply to apps built using the Android for Cars App Library

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the **debug app** for testing, which could be the reason for this.

To do a test on manufacturing Android Auto, your app must have a **released variant** to conduct the test on the production vehicle's Android Auto.

I also had the same issue, but it got fixed after the release variant.

I hope this helps.